# How to Change Latex texlive/2020 but not 2019?

Tags: installing, paths, versions

I installed the 2020 version from [the official source](https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html) via MacTex.pkg on MacOS. But the latex version is still 2019.

I need a package called `capt-of.sty` but not found, showed as below:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `capt-of.sty' not found.
```

So I check the file location and guess it's related to a problem of the old version but I don't know how to change to the new one even I already installed it.

---

Commands:

```
latex --version
```

It shows:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019)
```

Type,

```
echo $PATH
```

It shows:

```
/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

Try,

```
ls /usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex
```

The `capt-of.sty` is not inside.

Then try,

```
ls /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex
```

The `capt-of.sty` is inside.

---

So I guess I just need to change the path to the 2020. What's the method?

Comment: On the command line, what does `echo $PATH` say? If it contains `texlive/2019`, you have to find the place where this variable is set. Depending on the shell you use, it may be in one of the dot-files (files starting with `.`) in your home dir, or in `/etc`.

Comment: you are still using texlive 2019 so you could change your path to texlive 2020, but capt-of has been in texlive for years so was in texlive 2019.

Comment: Why not use TeX Live Utility to change the default version?